# How to use Composite Primary key in Xamarin Forms and SQLite.Net

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I want to have a class/Table in my Xamarin Forms app as follows. I want a composite primary key PersonId and PhotoId and only have PhotoId increment while PersonId is a foreign key back to the Person class/Table

```
public class Photo
{
   [PrimaryKey]
   public int PersonId {get; set;}

   [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
   public int PhotoId {get; set;}
}
```

Is that the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm#sqlite-attributes) states, Composite primary keys are not supported so far in SQLite.Net:

> [PrimaryKey] – This attribute can be applied to an integer property to
>   force it to be the underlying table's primary key. Composite primary
>   keys are not supported.

There are also some revelant issues in Github: [Composite key](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/134) and [Support multiple primary keys](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/280)